# How to overwrite data in the database? [ASP.NET]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This code saves my data to the database. The app records the time spent on each day of the month.

They write to the database in SQL Server, using EF. The problem is just that I would like them to overwrite instead of writing more

**Controller:**

```
List<Karta_Model> objNextKartaModel = new List<Karta_Model>();

for (int i = 0; i < liczbaDni; i++)
{
     var modelNext = new Karta_Model()
     {
         Login = userName,
         Rok = numerRoku,
         Miesiac = numerMiesiaca,
         DzMiesiaca = modelKarta.Model1[i].DzMiesiaca.Value,
         DzTygodnia = modelKarta.Model1[i].DzTygodnia,
         Rozpoczecie = modelKarta.Model1[i].Rozpoczecie
         ....
    };

    objNextKartaModel.Add(modelNext);

    await _ecpContext.Karta.AddRangeAsync(objNextKartaModel);
    await _ecpContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

`Id` in SQL Server is defined as:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1)
```

I came up with the idea to extract the first row ID from the previously saved database

```
var nrIdBase = _ecpContext.Karta
                          .FirstOrDefault(f => f.DzMiesiaca == 1 && 
                                               f.Miesiac == numerMiesiaca && 
                                               f.Rok == numerRoku && 
                                               f.Login == userName).Id;
```

but I don't know how to use it.

I tried something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < liczbaDni; i++)
{
     var modelNext = new Karta_Model()
     {
         Id = nrIdBase +i,
         Login = userName,
         Rok = numerRoku,
         Miesiac = numerMiesiaca,
         DzMiesiaca = modelKarta.Model1[i].DzMiesiaca.Value,
         DzTygodnia = modelKarta.Model1[i].DzTygodnia,
         Rozpoczecie = modelKarta.Model1[i].Rozpoczecie
         ....
     };
}
```

but I get an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Karta_Model' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

*Does anyone have an idea how to do this?*

*How to overwrite saved data once?*

Comment: Since you want to override the saved data, can't you just delete the one in the database first, then you can save the new data?... This approach depends on how much data you have in the database already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update an existing recording in a database, you need to have it's ID before the update operation.

Then you can do this:

```
var existingRecord = _ecpContext.Karta.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == theExistingId);

if (existingRecord != null) {
  existingRecord.Login = "CHANGED";
  await _ecpContext.SaveChangesAsync()
}
```

This call that you are using:

```
await _ecpContext.Karta.AddRangeAsync(objNextKartaModel);
```

Is only for adding new items to the database.

Comment: I don't understand this code. What should I substitute for 'theExistingId'?

Comment: The id of the database entity

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea in my comment above, one thing you can do is to delete the existing data in the table before adding the new ones.

```
List<Karta_Model> objNextKartaModel = new List<Karta_Model>();

for (int i = 0; i < liczbaDni; i++)
{
     var modelNext = new Karta_Model()
     {
         Login = userName,
         Rok = numerRoku,
         Miesiac = numerMiesiaca,
         DzMiesiaca = modelKarta.Model1[i].DzMiesiaca.Value,
         DzTygodnia = modelKarta.Model1[i].DzTygodnia,
         Rozpoczecie = modelKarta.Model1[i].Rozpoczecie
         ....
    };

    objNextKartaModel.Add(modelNext);

    //Add logic to delete the existing data
    foreach(var model in _ecpContext.Karta)
    {
       _ecpContext.Karta.Remove(model);
    } 

    await _ecpContext.Karta.AddRangeAsync(objNextKartaModel);
    await _ecpContext.SaveChangesAsync();//One SaveChanges call is enough to update the database
}
```

Comment: and what would such logic look like?

Comment: I've added a possible logic for deleting all the data you have in the database before you persist the new ones